# QRadar, parsing Log

Tags: text-parsing, qradar

I want to parse some application log, I did a lot of regex that works correctly with `notepad++` and the website [www.regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com) . 
But when I apply them in `QRadar` they don't match nothing.

**For example**

> 12/2/2017 9:53:58,4040007,blablablbla,blablabla --- Abonnement Mobile  N° : 0663016666 |  balbalbal | 03/06/2006 11:11:22  --- Soldes,10.10.10.10

I did this regex `(?<=---)\s+[A-Za-z+ \/\w+0-9._%+-]+(?=(\sN°|\s\sN°|\sID))` to match `Abonnement mobile` it works correctly , but it doesn't match anything in `QRadar`.

Answer (score 1):

QRadar does not accept all regex configurations. When you try parsing something you can use extract property field to check. Here is a regex that works fine in my system.

```
 \-\-\-\s(\w+\s\w+)\s
```

this regex will work if only "Abonnement Mobile" field is includes letters or digits. If you want to catch "Abonnement Mobile N°" you can use this regex and this will work whatever comes in this field.

```
 \-\-\-\s([^\:]+)\:
```

Comment: thanks for u're replay, i'll check this regex Monday because i don't have access to my system now and i'll tell you if it's work

Comment: hello, this regex work but the same problem with mine it match 'abonnement mobile' with '---' i want only abonnement mobile without any other thing

Comment: i find the solution 

'---\s+[A(-Za-z+ /\w+0-9._%+-]+(?=(\sN°|\s\sN°|\sID)))'
and in the capture groupe we must do $1 and it match only abonnement mobile without ---